# How to use sumifs formula with horizontal table (and data range)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which I need help with.

I have already took sum with

`=SUM(INDEX(B3:K7,MATCH(A13,A3:A7,0),0))`

formula and need to get the sum for specific data range. Like sum only for last 3 days from today.

[image]
 Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SUMPRODUCT variant

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(A13,A3:A7)+2&":K"&MATCH(A13,A3:A7)+2),--(B2:K2>=(B10-3)),--(B2:K2<="B10"))
```

UPDATED

To have the formula in different sheet you need to include the sheet references. I suggested cutting and pasting it from Sheet2 to Sheet1 but missed out that the part inside INDIRECT will not be adjusted by Excel automatically.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B"&MATCH(A13,Sheet2!A3:A7)+2&":ZZ"&MATCH(A13,Sheet2!A3:A7)+2),--(Sheet2!B2:ZZ2>=(TODAY()-7)))
```

Comment: How about i keep adding more data daily and still keep showing sum only for last 3 days from today. Can we extend (B2:K2) date range.

Comment: And the data is on sheet 2, formula should be on sheet 1.

Comment: OK, include the sheet reference in the address. Just enter formula in sheet1 and then cut and paste both name cell and formula cell and Excel will do that for you.

Comment: How can i attached the excel file here.